# How can use images from URLs in a list for use later on in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, web-scraping, request

I'm creating a GUI in Tkinter to view images.

This code works:

```
image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("/path/1.jpeg"))
image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("/path/2.jpeg"))
images = [image1, image2]
```

The images aren't displayed on the screen immediately and it works with the rest of my code (where I can click arrow keys to cycle between the images in the array).

However, when I try to use URLs instead of the path in the current directory, it doesn't work and the image gets shown immediately.

This is what I did:

```
class Article:
    def __init__(self, headline, description, link, image_url):
        self.headline = headline
        self.description = description
        self.link = link
        self.cover_image_url = image_url

from urllib.request import urlopen, Request

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3'}
images = []

articles = [#some list of Article objects]

for article in articles:
    url = article.cover_image_url
    request = Request(url = url, headers = headers) 
    data = urlopen(request).read() 
    images.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(BytesIO(data))))

frame = Label(root, image = images[0])
frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3)
status = Label(root, text = "Image Number: 1")

def forward(image_number):
    global frame
    global nextb
    global prev

    frame.grid_forget()
    frame = Label(root, image = images[image_number - 1])
    
    nextb = Button(root, text = ">>", command = (lambda: forward(image_number + 1)))
    prev = Button(root, text = "<<", command = (lambda: backward(image_number - 1)))
    status = Label(root, text = "Image Number: " + str(image_number))

    if image_number == len(images):
        nextb = Button(root, text = ">>", state = DISABLED)

    frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan= 3)
    nextb.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
    prev.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    status.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
  
    return

def backward(image_number):
    global frame
    global nextb
    global prev

    frame.grid_forget()
    frame = Label(root, image = images[image_number - 1])
    
    nextb = Button(root, text = ">>", command = (lambda: forward(image_number + 1)))
    prev = Button(root, text = "<<", command = (lambda: backward(image_number - 1)))
    status = Label(root, text = "Image Number: " + str(image_number))

    if image_number == 1:
        prev = Button(root, text = "<<", command = backward, state = DISABLED)

    frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan= 3)
    nextb.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
    prev.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    status.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    return 

prev = Button(root, text = "<<", command = backward, state = DISABLED)
prev.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
nextb = Button(root, text = ">>", command = (lambda: forward(2)))
nextb.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
status.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
#close = Button(root, text = "Close", command = root.quit)
#close.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

I want it to work like the first example where it shows me the arrow keys as well and I can cycle through images but it's not doing that.

Comment: There are many unknown stuff: what are `articles`, `Request` (`urllib.request.Request`?), etc?  Better post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `frame = Label(root, image = images[0])` will show the first image in the list.  So what is your problem actually?  If you don't want any image shown initially, you should not set the `image` option of `frame`.

Comment: It is a bad idea to re-draw the buttons and the Label each time you click on the << and >> buttons. Your callbacks for backwards and forwards should just update the image inside the label.

Comment: What can I do to fix it? @acw1668

Comment: As I said in my last comment, I don't get what your problem is actually.  So you better elaborate more clearly on what you want.

Comment: My bad, the problem is that in the case of using the URLs, the image appended to the list gets shown immediately without the buttons. If I use local files and add them to the array, I get shown all the buttons and the whole UI and I can smoothly cycle back and forth between my images. @acw1668

Comment: You have just repeat what you have said in the question without more details. As I said in my past comment: `frame = Label(root, image = images[0])` will show the first image in the list, is it what you want? Also what does *"the image appended to the list gets shown immediately without the buttons"* mean? I have tested your code (after adding missing parts), it only show the first image in the list, not all the images.  So once again, I don't get what your problem is.

Comment: @DiscJockey7733 acw1668 already said you are doing wrong there, but if you want to hard code for just 2 image then I believe you are right but this not how usually program are written, if you can automate then just do that so, in your case automate mean working with as many image you have in articles. But I don't think you are doing that. You are just trying to hardcode for 2 image only!

Comment: @Xitiz I guess what I'm trying to ask is how can I adapt this to work for any number of image URLs from Article objects? I'm running a function first that creates article objects and save the name and URL into variables and I want to display all those images with the article title underneath it.

Comment: @DiscJockey7733 I don't think I can help you with complete code but I can gave you a complete idea to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
from tkinter import Tk,Button,Label
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import io
import requests
import urllib 

root=Tk()

url="<link>"
url1="<link>"
url2="<link>"
url3="<link>"

count=0

urls=[url,url1,url2,url3]
labels=["label 1","label 2","label 3","label 4"]

images=[]
for ur in urls:
    raw_data = urllib.request.urlopen(ur).read()
    im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(raw_data))
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    images.append(image)

def change(direction):
    global count
    if direction=="left":
        if count<=0:
            count=len(urls)-1
        else:
            count-=1
    else:
        if count>=len(urls)-1:
            count=0
        else:
            count+=1
    name.config(text=labels[count])
    l.config(image=images[count])

Label(root).grid(row=1,column=1)
l=Label(root,image=images[count])
l.grid(row=1,column=2)

lb=Button(root,text="Left",command=lambda : change("left"))
lb.grid(row=2,column=1)

name=Label(root,text=labels[count])
name.grid(row=2,column=2)

rb=Button(root,text="Right",command=lambda : change("right"))
rb.grid(row=2,column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

I believe code is self explanatory. You have to play with it for some time to understand completely and use in your code.